# How do i do a multiple dependent REST API Call in meteor and store the response in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am newbie to Meteor and there is this requirement that i need to implement, On a Click of a button i need to get the data from the Rest API Store it to the DB and then show the same data on the UI. There are 2 server call i need to do, second call is dependent on the first call and will have parameter passed from the first call.

*Here's what i have implemented so far.*

```
<template name="inputButton">
  <input type="button" value="Get Data" />
</template>

if (Meteor.is_client) {
  Template.inputButton.events = {
    'click input' : function () {
        Meteor.call('getServerData',function(err, response) {
             console.log(response);
        });

    }
  };
}

if (Meteor.is_server) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.methods({
      getServerData: function () {
        this.unblock();
        var url = 'URL';
        return Meteor.http.get(url);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I know in the callback of Meteor.call i can insert the data to Mongodb, but how do i do one more request to different API using the parameter of first one ? Even the second response should be stored in the DB.

Is there any good meteor package to implement the same ? Could anyone also let me know what would be the best approach to implement the same ?

One more doubt i have is whether i can store the data to DB in the Server Code itself rather than returning to the client and then storing it ?

**Thank You**

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work ..

```
   Meteor.methods({
      getServerData: function () {
        this.unblock();
        var url1 = 'URL';
        var url2 = 'URL2';

        let result1 = HTTP.get(url1);

        let result2 = HTTP.get(url2, {data: result1});

        MyCollection.insert({result1, result2});

        return [result1, result2];
      }
    });
```

Comment: the first call gives me a json and the json will have say 10 usernames and based on the each username i need to do one more call to get the user details. Second api takes one user at a time.